# Use sys_arg in python config parser

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my config file in the format given below.

```
[Connection]
Oracle=Some Value
MySql=Some Value

[Queries]
productionTable1=Somevalue
productionTable2=Somevalue
```

Now I want to write a program file which would take the connection and table name as input and fetch me the corresponding values from the config file.

I wrote a code like this :

```
import sys
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read('mytest.ini')
config.sections()
connection_name=sys.argv[0]
load_query=sys.argv[1]
Myconnection=config.get("Connections","{}".format(connection_name))
My_load_query=config.get("Queries","{}".format(load_query))
print(Myconnection)
print(My_load_query)
```

But when I run the command "python3 test3.py Oracle productionTable1"

I get the below error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'test3.py' in section: 'Connections'
```

So could anyone help me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is  the script name. You need to use `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`.

Comment: or for better handling you can use `argparse.ArgumentParser` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the first argument (`sys.argv[0]`) is always the name of the file. So you need to use `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` to get to your values.